# How do I implement zooming where the cursor is located?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am developing a browser-based web application at work, and my boss is wanting me to implement zooming at certain spots in the viewport (where the cursor is currently located). This functionality would be similar to Google Maps where you can zoom in at certain spots on the map. Essentially, when the user positions the cursor on a certain spot, on wheel he shall be able to zoom into that point on the element.

Below is an image of what my app looks like in the browser:
[image]

I am not using `transform:scale()` for the scaling. Instead, I have a scale factor I set, and I multiply both the width and height by that scale factor to achieve the results of the size.

I wanted to mention, I am not using any frontend frameworks or libraries, in exception to KonvaJS for the lines. I am mainly using vanilla JS, or really, TypeScript.